# Salesforce production server shows less(50%) code coverage than sandbox(100%)?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have create trigger in sandbox and did run tests also, it covered 100%. But while deploying into production server it is throwing a message **Deploy Err : Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 50%, at least 75% test coverage is required.**

Help me some one on this......?

```
trigger TestTrigger on Case (before insert,before update,after insert) 
{
    Case ca =  Trigger.new[0]; 
    String sub = ca.Subject;



    if(sub.toUpperCase().startsWith('POP') || sub.toUpperCase().startsWith('POI'))
    {    




    }
}
```

Comment: What is your % of coverage in production when you run ALL tests, before you try to deploy the trigger?  Are there any errors in the Sandbox when you run all tests?  What is your total % of coverage in your sandbox when you run ALL tests and not just the ones involving this trigger?  Can you post both your trigger code and test code?

Comment: no errors in sandbox,sandbox code coverage is 100% when i run all test at once.

Comment: Try running all tests in production and see what the % is before adding this trigger and test class. Is it lower than 75%?

Comment: I ran all tests in production, it showed 100% coverage.

Comment: Is TestClass being deployed at the same time as TestTrigger? That could explain the lack of coverage in production. That, or there is another trigger in production on Case that is interfering.

Comment: I tried deploying both in same change set and tried with only TestTrigger also. Some how TestClass already deployed in production server. Yes, there is some other trigger/testcase which will creates new cases, It is on Account class before update trigger

Comment: Ideally if TestClass is already in production and TestTrigger isn't it should be failing on an assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a couple of reasons for this:

- Is your test class dependent on data or custom settings that only exist in your sandbox?
- Do you have extra classes or code in production? This can even be in the form of installed packages, etc.

Test coverage is calculated based on the total number of tested Apex statements (or lines) divided by the total number of Apex statements in your organization.

Comment: I have pasted my trigger and test case. My test dependent data and i have extra classes in production server.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't notice that. I am depending some Account objects which are only exist in sandbox.